# NetModel's cache in which folder?

Tags: built-in-symbols, neural-networks, caching

`NetModel` will produce a big cache file after you use it first time.

```
N[NetModel[#,"ByteCount"]/1024^2]&/@{
"LeNet Trained on MNIST Data",
"SqueezeNet V1.1 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data",
"GloVe 50-Dimensional Word Vectors Trained on Wikipedia and Gigaword-5 Data",
"GloVe 100-Dimensional Word Vectors Trained on Wikipedia and Gigaword-5 Data",
"GloVe 300-Dimensional Word Vectors Trained on Wikipedia and Gigaword-5 Data",
"Inception V1 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data",
"Inception V1 Trained on Places365 Data",
"Inception V3 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data",
"VGG-16 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data",
"Wolfram ImageIdentify Net for WL 11.1"
}//Total
```

> 1435.54

My computer cannot afford so many space.I want to delete it,but I fail to find it though I have used [Everthing](http://www.voidtools.com/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can semi-officially use this special property to see where a particular net model is stored:

```
In[27]:= NetModel["GloVe 300-Dimensional Word Vectors Trained on \
Wikipedia and Gigaword-5 Data", "ContentElementLocations"]

Out[27]= <|"EvaluationNet" -> 
  LocalObject[
   "file:///Users/taliesinb/Library/Wolfram/Objects/Resources/0e4/\
0e4cb9f7-9860-4111-855c-413658c3cdf1/download/EvaluationNet/\
41f18e3b11f833a6/data"], 
 "UninitializedEvaluationNet" -> CloudObject[
  "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/2f5f4e4d-83f4-484e-bc68-\
d4854e5e943b"], 
 "ConstructionNotebookExpression" -> CloudObject[
  "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/c4bdf7d3-7d48-4cef-aa4f-\
0523aee20145"]|>
```

The WLNet is "data.WLNet" under the directory mentioned in the "EvaluationNet" property, in this case `"/Users/taliesinb/Library/Wolfram/Objects/Resources/0e4/0e4cb9f7-9860-4111-855c-413658c3cdf1/download/EvaluationNet/41f18e3b11f833a6/data/data.WLNet"`.

You can delete all the cached NetModels by writing

```
Get["NeuralNetworks`"]; 
NeuralNetworks`Private`netModelRemove[]
```

In 11.1.1 that function will be uppercased however.

Comment: Good dig.Thanks very much.

Comment: Is there a way to get a list of the names of the available models in NetModel?

Comment: @xslittlegrass not currently but that's being added soon. Also, there will be an official repository website that lets you browse things, similar to the data repository (https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/)

Comment: That would be great to have! Looking forward to it.

Answer (score 3):

Win+R to open the Run dialog.

Enter `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\Wolfram\Objects\Resources`

You can find files by extension `.wlnet`. They are in directories with random names. For example: `Resources\08f\08fd9fd6-8bfb-4f9f-88b2-c4334919bcfd\download\EvaluationNet\41f18e3b11f833a6\data\data.WLNet`

Comment: Are you sure that will produce a `.wlnet` file?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.You can import this network directly without `NetModel`. `net = Import["data.WLNet"]`

Comment: @xslittlegrass Sorry for disturbing,this description is same to you?

Comment: I cannot find any `.wlnet` file in my local disk after I run `NetModel["LeNet Trained on MNIST Data"]`.

Comment: http://www.fastswf.com/hv7I-VI

Comment: I'm sorry,I can not [see anything](https://ooo.0o0.ooo/2017/03/31/58de03a2a47ba.jpg) in your link..

Comment: Enable Flash in your browser.

Comment: In Google Chrome you don't need to install anything. Go `chrome://settings/content` - Flash - Allow sites to run Flash.

Comment: I find that eventually..